# data.table add column sum by

Tags: data.table, data-wrangling

```
start <- data.table(team=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'),
                 pts=c(5, 8, 10, 5, 5, 9, 10))
end <- data.table(team=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'),
                     pts=c(5, 8, 10, 5, 5, 9, 10),
                  total_pts=c(13,13,20,20,20,19,19))


endtest <- start[, `:=` .(total_pts = sum(pts)), by=team]
```

Can you fix the "endtest" to get the dt end starting from the dt start?

Comment: `start[, total_pts := sum(pts), by=team]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot in the `.(` is incorrect for two reasons:

1. When you use `` `:=`(..) ``, R expects a parenthesis after the function, not a dot, the fix is to remove the dot and use  just

   ```r
   start[, `:=`(total_pts = sum(pts)), by=team]
   ```
2. If you do just `start[, .(total_pts=..), by=team]`, that parses correctly, and the `.(..)` means "replace the contents of my table with what is inside these parens", meaning it will produce (here) three rows, one per `team`.

   ```r
   start[, .(total_pts = sum(pts)), by=team]
   #      team total_pts
   #    <char>     <num>
   # 1:      a        13
   # 2:      b        20
   # 3:      c        19
   ```

   Since you do not want to *summarize*, it is not what you should use. Use just

   ```r
   start[, total_pts := sum(pts), by=team]
   #      team   pts total_pts
   #    <char> <num>     <num>
   # 1:      a     5        13
   # 2:      a     8        13
   # 3:      b    10        20
   # 4:      b     5        20
   # 5:      b     5        20
   # 6:      c     9        19
   # 7:      c    10        19
   ```